How is complex number $i$ valid in phasors?
I get it that a a complex number has two components, one of which can be considered to be the value of the phasor and the angle can be considered the phase. Also, adding two phasors produces similar results to adding complex numbers.
What I don't understand is how is considering $i^2=-1$ making sense when considering phasors?
In this 3B1B video, the narrator uses the property of complex numbers $|z|^2=z\overline z$, so we are not only considering the ability of separating complex numbers into components as a mathematical analogy but also considering the mathematical results of operating on complex numbers. How does this make sense?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109736/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/281085/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80028/2451 and links therein.
